# Probability of getting absorbed in an absorbing Markov Chain

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

Given a Markov Chain with 5 states: 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 where states 4 and 5 are absorbing. This is given by the transition diagram below. What is the probability of getting absorbed at state 5 given that you start at state 1.

I think I am supposed to use first-step analysis but I am confused. Any help would be great!
[image: Transition Diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Let $h_k$ be the probability of absorption in $5$, given that you start in state $k$. Doing the usual one step analysis, we get the equations
\begin{align*}
h_1 &= ph_2+(1-p)h_3 \\
h_2 &= (1-p)h_3 \\
h_3 &= ph_2 + (1-p).
\end{align*}
Solve the bottom two equations to get $h_3=\frac{1-p}{p^2-p+1}$, $h_2=\frac{(1-p)^2}{p^2-p+1}$ and so $\boxed{h_1=\tfrac{(1-p)^2(p+1)}{p^2-p+1}}$.